# Why does my Try and except block not execute the try block in a 'while loop'?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, while-loop, try-catch

I've been working on a project using selenium and python, I tried to make a loop in which my script tries to buy an item by clicking on an element. If the element is not found it refreshed the page and tried again. But when it refreshed, say 50 times, and a result popped up, it didn't buy the element, but it ignored it and kept refreshing. I think there's a fairly easy solution to my problem, but I can't seem to find it (probably because I'm a beginner).
This is the code I wrote:

```
while (True):
    try:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        kopen = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'The element')
        kopen.click()
        bevkoop = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'The element')
        bevkoop.click()
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        trg = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'The element')
        trg.click()
        bnpup = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'The element')
        bnpup.click()
        time.sleep(60 / 100)
        zoeken.click()
```

I already desperately tried to implement the 'time.sleep(0.3)' to try to make sure that my program actually checked if the element was there before just going to the except block immediately, but of course, that didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong.
Let's say the element was not found, this causes exception to be thrown.
`except NoSuchElementException` catches the exception. OK.
But then you trying again to click on that element that is not found!
What you can do:
Try clicking the element inside `try` block and in case of failure just put a sleep inside the `except` block or just nothing since you already have sleep at the beginning of the `try` code and try again, as following:

```py
while (True):
    try:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'The element').click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'The element').click()
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that all 4 XPATH’s are different elements, the  ones in the ‘except’ block are for refreshing the page (which works) but then after it’s refreshed and an items pops up, it refreshes again instead of executing the ‘try’ block, which SHOULD buy the item

Comment: I already fixed the problem, Thank you for taking the time to try to help me though

Comment: Nice to know that. You are welcome!